# sshfs for windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1, sshfs, dokan

I want to mount a remote Linux server as a drive to my windows 8.1.   That way I can use windows explorer to open up files that are on the Linux server and edit them without having to make a copy to the HDD on my on computer.

I tried Dokan, but it says my operating system is not supported.

What else can I do?

Comment: did u tried connecting using samba server.disable SMB 2.0 and 3.0 on the 8.1 machines so they could stay connected to the Samba shares.

Comment: I haven't tried that.  Can you recommend a url I can read up on how to do that exactly? Thanks